# cannot access local webserver mac osx lion

Tags: mac-osx, localhost

When i try to access my local webserver on my Macbook Pro 15".

i keep getting 403 Forbidden

I have eveything correctly set up in: my hosts en vhosts files. Also is the chmod of the directory in question 0755.

Any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: You missed some pertinent information, like the URL you are trying to access, and what is in "toby.conf" as you describe below.

Comment: Check apache's logfiles (access.log and error.log), they should tell you the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is an permissions problem. Can you please give us information which webserver you use? Ah, and which User/Group are the Owner of your www dir?

Comment: i use apache2 which comes standard with mac osx i have the user: toby.conf which is the user i am currently on

Comment: Agreed.  403 -> You DID access the web server and it refused to give you the file requested.  Most common reason is that the web server process doesn't have permissions to read the file.